# Can't install HoNClient-3.4.3.sh

Tags: command-line, 14.04, bash, scripts

I'm desktop user. My OS running 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04LTS. The problem I've run into is this: When I try to run the [client](http://dl.heroesofnewerth.com/HoNClient-3.4.3.sh) in the terminal, using the command:

```
sudo sh HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

it gives me this:

```
sh: 0: Can't open HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

I've gone through and made the file executable, but it still doesn't work. Same thing happens when I try:

```
./HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

Tried after making it executable double click it so it would open and i could run and install it but it opens as text document as it shouldn't.

After these problem I still tryed to run `HoNClient<ver>.sh` for a past few days but nothing worked, tried almost everything i found in google, but failed, if anyone have any suggestions and/or know how to fix this problem pls reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and go to the directory where you downloaded `HoNClient-3.4.3.sh` and type:

```
chmod 777 ./HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

Then all you need to do is to start the program like this:

```
./HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

It should not be a problem of 32 vs 64 bits as both are included in this 2.3 GB file:

[image]

I tested the md5sum of `HoNClient-3.4.3.sh`:

```
$ md5sum ./HoNClient-3.4.3.sh 
9aea6d7dc07c959deda9819b23b079b2  ./HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

Make sure that what you downloaded also have returns `9aea6d7dc07c959deda9819b23b079b2`.

Finally I tested installation on 14.04 64 bits, maybe it's just the 32 bits which is broken. Try the same file on a 14.04 64 bits, it should just work.